# Where to put code that downloads and stores data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, organization

I'm pretty much new to Rails and have a question about how to organize my code. I read about fat models and skinny controllers and it makes a lot of sense (in theory?).

What I'd like to do now is this: Periodically (via Cron and a Rails runner) download some data from the Internet and store parts of it in the database. What I don't understand is where to put the code which speaks with the API from which I get the data. Do I put it into the model and let it look like this:

```
API data
    '--> Model --> Database
```

What about another case where the downloaded data has to be split up and stored in two different models / database tables? Which version do is choose?

Version 1:

```
API data
    '--> Model --> Database
            '--> Model --> Database
```

Version 2:

```
API data
    '--> Controller
            |--> Model --> Database
            '--> Model --> Database
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: You could create a service object or something. `app/service_objects/download_data_from_api.rb`

Comment: ^ that's not a bad idea. I've often written it as a rake task, so it goes until `lib/tasks`. Then cron just executes the rake command.

Comment: I would argue that it is perfectly fine to have Ruby classes living in the models folder that aren't inherit from ActiveRecord. Btw you can run Ruby methods directly with `rails runner "Model.method"`, no need for an rake task.

Answer (score 0):

As @agmcleod suggested you should go with raketask, which you run with `rake task_name`, and then add to it cron jobs

Start with:

`rails g task api_service fetch_data_for_model1 fetch_data_for_model2`

now open `lib/tasks/api_service.rake`

```
namespace :api_servicedo
  desc "Update database with new Movies"
  task :fetch_data_for_model1=> :environment do
     puts 'start fetching data'
     API.new(credentials).fetch_movies.each do |movie|
        puts "creating movie id =#{movie.id}"
        Movie.find_or_create_by(movie.attributes)
     emd
     puts 'Finisheed!'
  end

  desc "TODO"
  task :fetch_data_for_model2=> :environment do
     ....
  end

end
```

now open

`crontab -e`

and give it rake task path

```
00 00 * * * cd /Users/you/projects/myrailsapp && /usr/local/bin/rake RAILS_ENV=production api_service:fetch_data_for_model1
```

You may consider using https://github.com/javan/whenever which  provides a clear syntax for writing and deploying cron jobs.

With whenever you would probably create `schedule.rb` file with such definitions

```
every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
    rake 'api_service:fetch_data_for_model1'
end
```